# Stripe Payment of Course using FireStore Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

So I have made a page where students will get redirected to after choosing in which course they want to register themselves and on that page the students will provide their personal information and right after they'll click on 'continue for registration' button a stripe checkout form will open that will charge them the amount of that particular course and only then those students will get registered in the cloud firestor database collection. So i started learning from these tutorials [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lZc2O2oUJk). However my cloud functions are written in NodeJS backend so i looked for some sample stripe apis for payment and found these sample apis on this github [repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js).

I am not sure how to hit these apis or if these are the right apis for me because my other functions are a little bit different then these stripe functions.
I would very much appreciate your help to know how can i implement this functionality. I am pasting the stripe fucntions here too.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const logging = require('@google-cloud/logging')();
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);
const currency = functions.config().stripe.currency || 'USD';

// [START chargecustomer]
// Charge the Stripe customer whenever an amount is created in Cloud Firestore
exports.createStripeCharge = functions.firestore.document('stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const val = snap.data();
      try {
        // Look up the Stripe customer id written in createStripeCustomer
        const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection(`stripe_customers`).doc(context.params.userId).get()
        const snapval = snapshot.data();
        const customer = snapval.customer_id
        // Create a charge using the pushId as the idempotency key
        // protecting against double charges
        const amount = val.amount;
        const idempotencyKey = context.params.id;
        const charge = {amount, currency, customer};
        if (val.source !== null) {
          charge.source = val.source;
        }
        const response = await stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key: idempotencyKey});
        // If the result is successful, write it back to the database
        return snap.ref.set(response, { merge: true });
      } catch(error) {
        // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-friendly way, while
        // still logging an exception with StackDriver
        console.log(error);
        await snap.ref.set({error: userFacingMessage(error)}, { merge: true });
        return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
      }
    });
// [END chargecustomer]]

// When a user is created, register them with Stripe
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
  return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({customer_id: customer.id});
});

// Add a payment source (card) for a user by writing a stripe payment source token to Cloud Firestore
exports.addPaymentSource = functions.firestore.document('/stripe_customers/{userId}/tokens/{pushId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
  const source = snap.data();
  const token = source.token;
  if (source === null){
    return null;
  }

  try {
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(context.params.userId).get();
    const customer =  snapshot.data().customer_id;
    const response = await stripe.customers.createSource(customer, {source: token});
    return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(context.params.userId).collection("sources").doc(response.fingerprint).set(response, {merge: true});
  } catch (error) {
    await snap.ref.set({'error':userFacingMessage(error)},{merge:true});
    return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
  }
});

// When a user deletes their account, clean up after them
exports.cleanupUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {
  const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).get();
  const customer = snapshot.data();
  await stripe.customers.del(customer.customer_id);
  return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).delete();
});
```

Angular Test Component(Not Sure about this)

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { PaymentService } from './payment.service';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-payment-request',
  templateUrl: './payment-request.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-request.component.scss'],
  providers: [PaymentService]
})
export class PaymentRequestComponent implements OnInit {

  // @Input() amount: 100;
  // @Input() label: 'Course';

  elements: any;
  paymentRequest: any;
  prButton: any;
  handler: any;
  amount: number = 500;
  confirmation: any;
  loading = false;

  @ViewChild('payElement', { static: true }) payElement;

  constructor(private pmt: PaymentService, private functions: AngularFireFunctions) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.loadStripe();
    // this.pmt.showId();
    this.pmt.showId();
    this.handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
      // key: environment.stripeKey,
      image: 'https://oc1.ocstatic.com/images/logo_small.png',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: token => {
        this.pmt.processPayment(token, this.amount)
      },
      source:  async (source) => {
        this.loading = true;
        const user = this.pmt.showId();
        firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('hxxxxxx.net')
        const fun = this.functions.httpsCallable('stripeCreateCharge');
        this.confirmation = await fun({ source: source.id, amount: this.amount}).toPromise();
        this.loading = false;
      }
    });
  }

  handlePayment(e) {
    const user = this.pmt.showId();
    this.handler.open({
      name: 'FireStarter',
      description: 'Pay your Dues',
      amount : this.amount,
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
 }
```

Comment: I am looking for a similar thing. Have you looked at this page. https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments

Comment: @Philip The steps in the above link are already used in angular app. I am getting token in realtime database too. The problem is just that i want to send the data in a firestore database collection and that function in return send the token back to stripe and the payment will be complete then and the payment record get saved into the database